# Principal Object is null when jwt token is not valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using spring security to authenticate users using jwt tokens. 
The authentication works fine, when the token is malformed or expired i get a 403 Http status, as shown in the below configuration:

```
 @Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> {
                return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED); 
                });
            }).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> {
                return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                });
            }).and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().build();
}
```

However when i use Principal or Authentication from spring security context to get user information from the jwt token, like in the below code:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@GetMapping("/me")
public Mono<ClientDTO> find(final Principal principal) {
    return this.clientService.findByMail(principal.getName());
}
```

If the token is malformed or expired, i get a null pointer exception from the Principal object and an 500 https status.

Comment: isn't .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll() disabling the jwt check for the endpoint?

Comment: As @Lacuno points out, it is counter productive to permitAll and then assume there will be a valid Principal. It almost seems like you want an Anonymous Principal if it is expired or malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@GetMapping("/me")
public Mono<ClientDTO> find(final Principal principal) { 

if(principal!=null) return this.clientService.findByMail(principal.getName());
else throw new CustomTokenExpiredException();
}
```

and remove
               `.pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()`

Answer (score 3):

*I want to apologize right away if my answer does not help with your problem, since I do not see all your code.*

---

I have a suitable project where I was able to check the work with the Principal object in similar conditions and everything works for me. Therefore, the problem is not in it.

---

You probably throw an exception in the token validation method. Something like that:

```
public boolean validateToken(String token) {
    try {
        Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);
        return true;
    } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new JwtAuthenticationException("JWT token is expired or invalid", e);
    }
}
```

In this case, the exception is caught before you catch it in the configuration. The solution may be to reject a new exception in the token validation method in favor of outputting information to the log:

```
public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
      try {
         Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
         return true;
      } catch (io.jsonwebtoken.security.SecurityException | MalformedJwtException e) {
         log.info("Invalid JWT signature.");
         log.trace("Invalid JWT signature trace: {}", e);
      } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
         log.info("Expired JWT token.");
         log.trace("Expired JWT token trace: {}", e);
      } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
         log.info("Unsupported JWT token.");
         log.trace("Unsupported JWT token trace: {}", e);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         log.info("JWT token compact of handler are invalid.");
         log.trace("JWT token compact of handler are invalid trace: {}", e);
      }
      return false;
}
```

I will be glad if this helps you. Otherwise, me need more information about your code.